# Python Pytesseract not detecting strings on image

Tags: python, tesseract

Hi I have a python code with tesseract, the goal is to detect strings from screenshot. Code:

```py
import pytesseract
import cv2
import pyautogui
import numpy as np

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

image = pyautogui.screenshot()
image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imwrite("images\gameScreenshot.png", image)

img = cv2.imread('images\gameScreenshot.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))

cv2.imshow('Result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I want it to print out, detect string like "Enemy, Enemy, Enemy", (don't ask what for okay :D)
But instead it prints out some garbage. Ex:

```
[|=Li]
2

fyi

TT fi)
938/100
10720
```

The image i display as a result on the end looks like this: [image: Result]
How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tesseract works on black and white image. By default on image of black text on white background. The first stage of tesseract is to binarize text, if it is not already binarized. You have to help it to do so. Either binarize yourself. Or, at least, providing and image with text as black as possible, and rest as white as possible.

For example, here, your text seems to be perfect red (255,0,0) (it appears blue in your example, because you mix up RGB2BGR somewhere. But sky color makes obvious that it is red in reality).

So, try to find a formula that makes red color 0, and other color 255. With some smooth transition in between.

For example (just my first shot, it is certainly improvable. Plus, there are many smarter method, providing your own binarization that you could use)

```py
im2=(255-img[:,:,2].clip(232,255) + img[:,:,0].clip(0,20) + img[:,:,1].clip(0,20))*3
```

Puts in black=0 pixels (255,0,0), and in white=255 those that are not (255,0,0), with some variation in between (for example, (250, 5, 5) is  (5+5+5)*3=45, so quite dark, but not black)

[image]

And, on this picture

```py
pytesseract.image_to_string(im2)
#" \n\n \n\n \n\nEnemy\nEnemy\n—\n8 of Enemy\n‘a -\n- .\n» ' >\n-. i\n“a ®, ow\n\n \n\x0c"
```

Not perfect, far from that. But at least, you see that you have your "Enemy Enemy Enemy" among some noise.

It will never be perfect anyway. There is no miracle.
My point is just to show that to start working, you need a black/white image, with black text over white background.

You could certainly improve the way to build that black&white image to exclude more noise.

### `to_data`

Besides all this, `image_to_string` is made for good old linear, top to bottom, left to right, linear text. This is not your case here.
For this kind of images, with scattered pieces of text, I would use `image_to_data` instead. That gives a list of text, their coordinate, confidence factor, and even some hierarchical organization (in pages, blocks, lines,...).

```py
print(pytesseract.image_to_data(im2))
```

shows

```
level   page_num    block_num   par_num line_num    word_num    left    top width   height  conf    text
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1533    890 -1  
2   1   1   0   0   0   69  43  4   57  -1  
3   1   1   1   0   0   69  43  4   57  -1  
4   1   1   1   1   0   69  43  4   57  -1  
5   1   1   1   1   1   69  43  4   57  95   
2   1   2   0   0   0   10  39  391 66  -1  
3   1   2   1   0   0   10  39  391 66  -1  
4   1   2   1   1   0   10  39  391 66  -1  
5   1   2   1   1   1   10  39  391 66  95   
2   1   3   0   0   0   1440    276 62  172 -1  
3   1   3   1   0   0   1440    276 62  172 -1  
4   1   3   1   1   0   1440    276 62  172 -1  
5   1   3   1   1   1   1440    276 62  172 95   
2   1   4   0   0   0   16  255 694 288 -1  
3   1   4   1   0   0   16  255 694 288 -1  
4   1   4   1   1   0   470 255 60  15  -1  
5   1   4   1   1   1   470 255 60  15  95  Enemy
4   1   4   1   2   0   286 352 94  23  -1  
5   1   4   1   2   1   286 352 94  23  95  Enemy
4   1   4   1   3   0   295 381 75  9   -1  
5   1   4   1   3   1   295 381 75  9   58  —
4   1   4   1   4   0   22  400 688 30  -1  
5   1   4   1   4   1   88  409 9   10  0   8
5   1   4   1   4   2   285 401 22  29  26  of
5   1   4   1   4   3   647 400 63  16  67  Enemy
4   1   4   1   5   0   49  420 271 15  -1  
5   1   4   1   5   1   49  423 16  12  13  ‘a
5   1   4   1   5   2   306 420 14  11  0   -
4   1   4   1   6   0   105 451 198 14  -1  
5   1   4   1   6   1   105 451 6   6   15  -
5   1   4   1   6   2   289 456 14  9   5   .
4   1   4   1   7   0   170 490 47  8   -1  
5   1   4   1   7   1   170 490 4   5   30  »
5   1   4   1   7   2   194 475 6   34  0   '
5   1   4   1   7   3   212 490 5   8   23  >
4   1   4   1   8   0   19  509 38  13  -1  
5   1   4   1   8   1   19  509 38  13  0   -.
5   1   4   1   8   2   187 504 14  8   15  i
4   1   4   1   9   0   16  534 232 9   -1  
5   1   4   1   9   1   16  535 12  8   19  “a
5   1   4   1   9   2   196 534 4   6   0   ®,
5   1   4   1   9   3   228 516 18  34  42  ow
2   1   5   0   0   0   392 487 1141    403 -1  
3   1   5   1   0   0   392 487 1141    403 -1  
4   1   5   1   1   0   392 487 1141    403 -1  
5   1   5   1   1   1   392 487 1141    403 95
```

See that lines with `conf` -1 are empty lines used only for hiearchy structure. And lines with conf<50% are trash. So let's parse (with some `split`) those data, and filter out the lines with less than 50% confidence factor.

```py
# Split lines (separated by \n), and in each of them fields, separated by \t
# Ignore first (header) and last (empty) lines
lines=[s.split('\t') for s in pytesseract.image_to_data(im2).split('\n')[1:-1]]
# Keeps only the one that have confidence factor>50
# and that are not just blank
[l[-1] for l in lines if int(l[-2])>50 and l[-1].strip()]
```

And result is... tadaa

```
['Enemy', 'Enemy', '—', 'Enemy']
```

Not, that bad, if I may say myself. Considering the very artisanal "first shoot" black&whitization.
Note that the `—` has a confidence factor 58, when the worst "Enemy" has 67, so I could have chosen a threshold of 60 instead of 50. But I don't want to cheat and adjust thresholds retroactively :D

Also, note that I kept only text here, but each "Enemy" comes with coordinates. You requested that we don't ask why you need to find "Enemy, Enemy, Enemy". so I didn't ask. But for most usage I can think of, being able to know the position is a plus, I guess.

Comment: tesseract WORKS on color images. However custom image thresholding could improve of OCR result. Problem of this image is text detection if complex images. I would suggest to try [EAST or Yolo][1] to detext text and then run image preprocessig + OCR.
 [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpRNfWzuexQ

Answer (score 0):

if can using sharp the image and more perfect image resolution and you can get perfect image and then using threshold the image and you using above step get unperfect output means then contour the image

Finally if you using change configuation of model

Comment: can you add some clairty into your answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you elaborate?